# hive partition data based on month not working showing Error: java.lang.RuntimeException: Error in configuring object

Tags: hadoop, hive, hiveql

**Data in access_log file like:**

> in24.inetnebr.com - - [01/Aug/1995:00:00:01 -0400] "GET
>   /shuttle/missions/sts-68/news/sts-68-mcc-05.txt HTTP/1.0" 200 1839

**space separated values so i created table schema like**

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS access_log (
  host STRING,
   identity STRING,
   apache_user STRING,
   time STRING,
   request STRING,
   status STRING,
   size STRING
)

ROW FORMAT SERDE 'org.apache.hadoop.hive.contrib.serde2.RegexSerDe' WITH SERDEPROPERTIES ( "input.regex" = "([^ ]*) ([^ ]*) ([^ ]*) (-|\\[[^\\]]*\\]) ([^ \"]*|\"[^\"]*\") (-|[0-9]*) (-|[0-9]*)", "output.format.string" = "%1$s %2$s %3$s %4$s %5$s %6$s %7$s" )  STORED AS TEXTFILE;
```

**table created successfully and loaded the data using below command:**

```
LOAD DATA LOCAL INPATH '${env:HOME}/work/pocs/3.weblogs/access_log.txt' OVERWRITE INTO TABLE access_log;


select time from access_log limit 2;
```

**i'm getting time result is :**

> [01/Aug/1995:00:00:01 -0400]
>
> [01/Aug/1995:00:00:07 -0400]

**so now i want to partition data based on month so i'm trying to create new table for partition data, in hive promt:**

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS access_log_partition (
  host STRING,
   identity STRING,
   apache_user STRING,
   request STRING,
   status STRING,
   size STRING
)
PARTITIONED BY (time string)
ROW FORMAT SERDE 'org.apache.hadoop.hive.contrib.serde2.RegexSerDe'
WITH SERDEPROPERTIES (
"input.regex" = "([^ ]*) ([^ ]*) ([^ ]*) ([^ ]*) ([^ \"]*|\"[^\"]*\") (-|[0-9]*) (-|[0-9]*)",
"output.format.string" = "%1$s %2$s %3$s %4$s %5$s %6$s %7$s"
)

STORED AS TEXTFILE;
```

**I created new table(access_log_partition) for partition data after that i want to partition data based on month so i'm verifying date format to partition data i used below command:**

```
select date_format(to_utc_timestamp(from_unixtime(unix_timestamp(time,'[dd/MMM/yyyy:HH:mm:ss z]')),'PST'),'MMM') as `mmm` from access_log limit 5;
```

**so the result is im getting like:**

> OK
>
> Aug
>
> Aug
>
> Aug
>
> Aug
>
> Aug
>
> Aug
>
> Aug
>
> Aug
>
> Aug
>
> Aug
>
> Time taken: 0.329 seconds, Fetched: 10 row(s)

**i want to partition data from access_log to access_log_partition table so i tried below command:**

```
INSERT OVERWRITE TABLE access_log_partition partition(time) select host, identity, apache_user, date_format(to_utc_timestamp(from_unixtime(unix_timestamp(time,'[dd/MMM/yyyy:HH:mm:ss z]')),'PST'),'MMM') as `mmm`, request, status, size from access_log;
```

**but i'm getting error like:**

Diagnostic Messages for this Task:

> Error: java.lang.RuntimeException: Error in configuring object    at
>   org.apache.hadoop.util.ReflectionUtils.setJobConf(ReflectionUtils.java:109)

**so please help me partition data based on month..**

Comment: As I already commented, `output.format.string` is deprecated. Remove it from your code

Comment: What can i replace with that, if i'm not provide that what is the default output format

Comment: Nothing, it meaningless. The SerDe does nothing with that parameter.

Comment: @DuduMarkovitz I removed output.format.string, same error repeated.

Comment: As I said, it is meaningless. Your mistakes go far beyond this. You can't use RegexSerDe for writing, only for reading. `access_log_partition` should use a "standard" SerDe.

Comment: You mean default SampleSerDe

Comment: No, I mean orc/parquet/sequencefile/textfile or whatever that can be used for both reading and writing.

Comment: I removed regexSerde for access_log_partition so default Serde(LazySimpleSerDe) will use internally and i changed file Stored as textfile to sequencefile for access_log_partition also still same error occurred

Comment: The error is: Error in configuring object

Comment: @DuduMarkovitz i tried all file format's still same error repeated and i removed regexSerde and its properties from access_log_partition still same error repeating.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
create external table access_log
(
    host        string 
   ,identity    string 
   ,apache_user string 
   ,time        string 
   ,request     string 
   ,status      string 
   ,size        string
)
row format serde        'org.apache.hadoop.hive.contrib.serde2.RegexSerDe' 
with serdeproperties    ('input.regex'='([^ ]*) ([^ ]*) ([^ ]*) (-|\\[[^\\]]*\\]) ([^ \"]*|\"[^\"]*\") (-|[0-9]*) (-|[0-9]*)') 
stored as textfile
;
```

---

```
select * from access_log
;
```

---

```
+-------------------+----------+-------------+------------------------------+----------------------------------------------------------------+--------+------+
|       host        | identity | apache_user |             time             |                            request                             | status | size |
+-------------------+----------+-------------+------------------------------+----------------------------------------------------------------+--------+------+
| in24.inetnebr.com | -        | -           | [01/Aug/1995:00:00:01 -0400] | "GET /shuttle/missions/sts-68/news/sts-68-mcc-05.txt HTTP/1.0" |    200 | 1839 |
+-------------------+----------+-------------+------------------------------+----------------------------------------------------------------+--------+------+
```

---

```
create table if not exists access_log_partition 
(
    host        string
   ,identity    string
   ,apache_user string
   ,request     string
   ,status      string
   ,size        string
)
partitioned by (time string)
stored as textfile
;
```

---

```
set hive.exec.dynamic.partition.mode=nonstrict:
```

---

```
insert into access_log_partition partition (time)

select  host,identity,apache_user,request,status,size
       ,date_format(to_utc_timestamp(from_unixtime(unix_timestamp(time,'[dd/MMM/yyyy:HH:mm:ss z]')),'PST'),'MMM') as `mmm` 

from    access_log
;
```

---

```
select * from access_log_partition
;
```

---

```
+-------------------+----------+-------------+----------------------------------------------------------------+--------+------+------+
|       host        | identity | apache_user |                            request                             | status | size | time |
+-------------------+----------+-------------+----------------------------------------------------------------+--------+------+------+
| in24.inetnebr.com | -        | -           | "GET /shuttle/missions/sts-68/news/sts-68-mcc-05.txt HTTP/1.0" |    200 | 1839 | Aug  |
+-------------------+----------+-------------+----------------------------------------------------------------+--------+------+------+
```

Comment: i tried all you sent still shows same thing:   Diagnostic Messages for this Task:
Error: java.lang.RuntimeException: Error in configuring object
 at org.apache.hadoop.util.ReflectionUtils.setJobConf(ReflectionUtils.java:109)
 at org.apache.hadoop.util.ReflectionUtils.setConf(ReflectionUtils.java:75)
 at org.apache.hadoop.util.ReflectionUtils.newInstance(ReflectionUtils.java:133)
 at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.runOldMapper(MapTask.java:446)

Comment: **(1)** This is a tested code **(2)** Obviously your error has nothing to do with this code. google it or open a new question, this time using a simple example and check it again after you take care of your Hadoop/Hive.